# Zeppelin: Scheduling a notebook

Tags: sql, scheduling, apache-zeppelin

I want to schedule a notebook on zeppelin Version 0.10.1 is there a way to do this easily or will I have to write a query in order to do this as cron job scheduling doesn't exist now and I can't create a new job to try and schedule so does anyone know how I can schedule my notebook to run four of my sql queries every 20 minutes for example.

So far I have only tried to create a new job and schedule it like that

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the property zeppelin.notebook.cron.enable to true in the zeppelin-site.xml file. you probably have to uncomment the section to make it work.